# convert <button> css style to <asp:button> style

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an `<button>` in my codes, now I want to change it to `<asp:button>` . but after replace, the design is so bad! I mean some style code does not work in new button.
you can see this in:
http://rogatech.somee.com/search.aspx
the black button in blue area is `<button>` and black button in white area has `<asp:button>` tag. you see that all the thing like color and size and mouse over effect not show in new button.
my codes:

```
<section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
    <form action="" method="">          
        <asp:textbox ID="Textbox1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" placeholder="Search...">   </asp:textbox>          
        <button>Search</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

style:

```
.webdesigntuts-workshop button {
    background: #222;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-left-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 80px;
}   

.webdesigntuts-workshop button:hover,
.webdesigntuts-workshop button:focus {
    background: #292929;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);   
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);  
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    color: #5f5;
    outline: none;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop button:active {
    background: #292929;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, inset 1px 0 1px #222;
    top: 1px;
}
```

how can I change this style for using in  ?
I tried to change :

```
<asp:button text="search" runat server cssClass="button"/>
```

and in css tried:
    .webdesigntuts-workshop button:hover
change to :

```
.webdesigntuts-workshop  form button:hover,
```

but some styles not work in new button!

Answer (score 1):

you have a form after the section so do

```
.webdesigntuts-workshop form button { //here }
```

Comment: need a jsfiddle or sth to see what you mean. edit your post please

Comment: I have edited my post.you can see my mean in http://rogatech.somee.com/search.aspx